# Why am I getting the error "cin does not name a type"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

While trying to write this code, I get an error `"cin doesnt name a type"`. 
I don't know what the problem is exactly and I tried to write "using namespace std;"
but it gave the same error.

Here's the code

```
#include<iostream>

namespace myStuff {

    int value = 0;

}

using namespace myStuff;

int main {

    std::cout << "enter integer " << ;
    std::cin >> value;
    std::cout << "\nyouhaveenterd a value" << value ;

    return 0;

}
```

Here's the compilation error :

```
: extended initializer lists only available with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` [enabled by default]|
: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token|
 expected `}` before `;` token|
 `cin` does not name a type|
: `cout` does not name a type|
: expected unqualified-id before `return`|
: expected declaration before `}` token|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int main{
```

should be

```
int main(){
```

and

```
std::cout << "enter integer " << ;
```

should be

```
std::cout << "enter integer ";
```

Comment: Thanks for solving , it's the best :)

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
std::cout << "enter integer " << ;
```

There's no corresponding operand to make the statement syntactically valid. That's probably the source of your errors.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I can see that now. Thanks to your answer which highlights the foremost problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its the previous line.

```
 cout<<"enter integer" **<<** ;
```

that last << is expecting an argument which is never given

Comment: Thanks so much , I didn't give attention to this line